# Saving a newly created workbook to a specific folder

Tags: vba, excel, macros, save

I hope you can help. 
I have a piece of code. 
Essentially what it does is, it opens a dialog box that allows a user to select an excel sheet, then it goes out to the country column (11) filters it, then copies and pastes that country into a new workbook, names the new workbook after that country then repeats the action for the next country, then it saves and closes each Workbook.

**What I would like to change is where these new workbooks are being saved.**

Currently they are being saved in the same folder where the Template (The Original workbook that gets split) and the Macro are stored. I would like the newly created Workbooks to be now saved somewhere else. Here C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\CRO Countries

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Pic of where the Workbooks are currently stored

[image]

Pic of the Original Template

[image]

MY CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your CRO file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)

    Call TestThis

    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

   With .Range("A1:Y" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Y" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(11).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 11th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 11, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (11th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add '<--... add new Workbook
                        wb.SaveAs Filename:=rCountry.Value2 '<--... saves the workbook after the country
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                               ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                           .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                           Sheets(1).Range("A1:Y1").WrapText = False 'Takes the wrap text off
                           ActiveWindow.Zoom = 55 'Zooms out the window
                         Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit 'Autofits the column
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub

Public Sub TestThis()
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

With wks
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Range("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 65535
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to give the full path to the `SaveAs` Method :

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\CRO Countries\" & rCountry.Value2 '<--... saves the workbook after the country
```

If you don´t give a full path, but rather just a filename, exel saves the file at the current folder, but with a full path, excel saves the file just at the position and with the name you indicate.

Comment: Cheers for this it was very helpful and gave me exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:=rCountry.Value2
```

to

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\CRO Countries\" & rCountry.Value2
```